# PHPFox persian url in IIS server transforms to question mark

Tags: url, iis, unicode-string, persian, phpfox

I have installed phpfox in a IIS server which supports php 5.x
But URLs transforms to ????? when i click on some persian links.
For example i should have a link like :

`http://mydomain.com/index.php?do=/photo/album/6/اخبار/`  which is like `http://mydomain.com/index.php?do=/photo/album/6/????????/`

Although i have this problem in my online windows based host, i have installed this version in localhost using XAMPP and it is running without problem.

I am newbie in php.

Comment: You need to encode the Unicode parts of the URL: http://us1.php.net//manual/en/function.urlencode.php (urlencode(utf8_encode($string)))

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Unfortunately, i donno where PhpFox generates URLs.
Do me a favor and please guide me to change the source code or specific function.