# Where is and which function does encode or decode URL in phpfox?

Tags: url, encoding, persian, phpfox

I'll be wonder if you tell me how phpfox handle URLs?
In details i want to know that which function gererates urls in PHPFox?
I have some problem with encoding or decoding of PHPFox. Because it transform some urls which is in Persian language to ??????.
For example it will resolve this link: 'http://www.mydomain.com/photos/اخبار/' to 'http://www.mydomain.com/photos/???????/'

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPFox persian url in IIS server transforms to question mark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349436/phpfox-persian-url-in-iis-server-transforms-to-question-mark)

Answer (score 0):

This is the main library class for URLs: `/include/library/phpfox/url/url.class.php`

Is this what you are looking for?